# Can I add some overlays on fullsceen videos on safari mobile (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, html, video, interactive

I'm working on a webapp that makes some interactive HTML5 videos, and run into a problem with iPhone.
I known that on safari mobile (iPhone), all videos will be ran in full-screen mode.
The question here is can I add some overlays (text, link, etc...) to this full-screen player (using html/js, maybe)?
Thanks so much!